# ANDROID: Using ShowcaseView library in ScrollView layouts

Tags: android, scrollview, showcaseview

I use showcaseview for user manual. As you see in following pictures. It works by touching Next bottom.

[image]

The problem is that I use ScrollView in my layout. However when showcaseview appears, the scrollview does not work. so, as you can see from second picture, showcase shows an elemen which placed at bottom of screen but the screen is not scroll-able. How can I change the schowcase in the way that it scroll down automatically for showing description of such elements. Or at least how can I add scroll ability to schowcaseview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even I faced a similar issue. So I used  a workaround using `requestFocus()` method.

Use following code.

```
view.setFocusable(true);
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Here `view` will be the object you wish to show in the showcaseview. Hope this will help you.